# C++ how to reload a bitmap after it has already been loaded

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a CBitmap that i have loaded a bitmap in:

```
bmpNumber.LoadBitmapA(IDB_SM_1_BMP);
```

but now i want to change the loaded bitmap.  I can't just call loadbitmap again.

Comment: I assume that loads a bitmap from disk. In that case you'll have to call load bitmap again. But you should really try to make changes to the copy in main memory, and save it if needed.

Comment: the bitmap is on disk, but calling loadbitmap again gives me an assertion error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling bmpNumber.DeleteObject() before the 2nd load.

Comment: I have to apologize.  I was looking at the wrong field in my code and it wasn't giving me the option to call DeleteObject().  I appreciate the help.